# Remove empty rows on table with php

Tags: php

I have table:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

<tr>

<th>Product</th>
<th>Service</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 1</td>
<td>S11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S14</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product 2</td>
<td>S11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>S120</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need: where empty row with product (where product's name is empty) delete this row and move service to up product row and delete current service from up product. Example:

In this table we have `product 1`. I need remove `S11` and paste: `S13` and `S14` in single row.

I need this table on result:

```html
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <table class="table-bordered" width="100%">

    <tr>

    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Service</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product 1</td>
    <td>S13, S14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Product 2</td>
    <td>S120</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I know how it can do with javascript:

```
let tr;
$('#test1234 tr').each(function () {
 if($(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().length){
    tr = $(this);
    tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').text('')
 }else{
    let td = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(2)');
    let comma = td.text() !== "" ? ", " : '';
    td.text(td.text() +  comma +  $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text())
    $(this).remove()
 }

});
```

But I need do this with php. How I can do it?
I have this html page on my php variable: `$html_body`.

Comment: can you add your result array in your question?

Answer (score 0):

> generally you can't remove it using php but i will give you suggestion that please use continue statement when your row is blank

for example

```
$html = "<tbody>";

foreach($data as $row){
    if(empty($row['parameter'])){
        continue;
    }else{
        $html .= "<tr> <td></td> </tr>";
    }
}
$html .= "</tbody>";
```

Comment: You don't concat `Services`